# XML Parsing Error: junk after document element

Tags: php, xml

I want to create an xml file from a database, and then to echo this file to use in another page for some ajax.

this is the code I use to create the xml file :

```
<?php

    header("Content-Type:text/XML");

    $connexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=produits;charset=utf8", 'root', 'toor'); 
    $statement = $connexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM produit"); 
    $statement->execute();

    $resultats = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $xml_file = new DOMDocument('1.0');

    $root = $xml_file->createElement('produits');


    foreach($resultats as $produit){

        $tel = $xml_file->createElement('telephone');
        $tel->setAttribute('id', $produit->id);

        $marque = $xml_file->createElement('marque');
        $marqueText = $xml_file->createTextNode($produit->marque);
        $marque->appendChild($marqueText);
        $tel->appendChild($marque);

        $model = $xml_file->createElement('model');
        $modelText = $xml_file->createTextNode($produit->model);
        $model->appendChild($modelText);
        $tel->appendChild($model);

        $prix = $xml_file->createElement('prix');
        $prix->setAttribute("devise", "DH");
        $prixText = $xml_file->createTextNode($produit->prix);
        $prix->appendChild($prixText);
        $tel->appendChild($prix);

        $root->appendChild($tel);
    }

    $xml_file->appendChild($root);

    echo $xml_file;
?>
```

The problem is  when I open the page to check if the xml file is create, I get this error message :

> XML Parsing Error: junk after document element Location:
>   `http://localhost/Ajax/produits/details.php` Line Number 2, Column
>   1: ^

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: What does the outputted XML look like?

Comment: `echo $xml_file->saveXML();`

Comment: @VolkerK: Good catch.  I didn't even notice they weren't actually echoing the XML.

Comment: It would be helpful to future visitors if @VolkerK woudl post his comment as an answer and the OP would accept it.

Answer (score 1):

$xml_file points to the DOMDocument instance. DOMDocument doesn't implement an implicit __toString() conversion, therefore `echo $xml_file;` results in output like

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMDocument could not be converted to string in ...
```

and the client-side xml parser complains about it not being a valid xml doc.

You want to output the xml representation of the dom which you can do e.g. via

```
echo $xml_file->saveXML();
```

see http://docs.php.net/domdocument.savexml